# Maven cannot Download from local repository (nexus) for some dependency or plugins

Tags: java, maven, repository, nexus

I have a project (java) with some modules and I have local repository nexus.
in pom.xml I set repository address :

```html
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-maven-repository</id>
            <url>http://nexus_repository:8080/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>local-maven-repository2</id>
            <url>http://nexus_repository:8080/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

But maven download from "repo.maven.apache.org" for some dependency or plugins. and for some dependency or plugins download from local repository .

Comment: pls share exact error here

Comment: I don't have error , during to download dependency from local repository, sometimes download them from "repo.maven.apache.org" that I dont have acess to internet directly and this took a time for build, (I am using from gitlab runner ) Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/2.4.0/maven-bundle-plugin-2.4.0.pom
 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/2.3.6/maven-bundle-plugin-2.3.6.pom

Comment: Is this in your settings.xml file?

Comment: do I need to setting.xml in .m2 path?

Comment: I configured repository address in pom.xml

Comment: It needs to be in ~/.m2.  See https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts.  The `settings.xml` file and your project's `pom.xml` file are different things.  The servers and mirrors settings need to be in the `settings.xml` file.

Comment: I answer in below comment